# UITableView Checkmarks after ReloadData() is called

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've done iOS developement with Xamarin for a while now but I recently noticed something weird that I don't understand. I want to put checkmarks on the left side of each row in my UITableView. When I call

`tableView.SetEditing(true, true)`

It nicely animates in a red delete buttons/circles on the left side of each row. If I right after call

`tableView.ReloadData()`

Then the red delete buttons/circle turn into checkmarks, so I can check the rows in the table. But it also interrupts the animation. How do I make it start with the checkmarks so I don't have to call `tableView.ReloadData()` ?

Comment: Are you talking about the Checkmarks that show if multiple selections are made?(AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true)

Comment: Yes. I'm setting that to true as well.

Comment: I am confused, so you want all the items selected so each row shows a green checkmark?

Comment: I just fixed it. The problem was that I was setting AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing to false each time I was turning edit mode off, which resulted in having delete buttons/circles on each row. Now I only set it to true once during initialization of the table and it works as expected. Thanks for the insight!